# Can't make an update work on my entity relation JPA

Tags: java, jpa

when I am trying to update a parentEntity , its not reflecting.

1. modify "Field2" in SecondEntity and call (saveAndFlush).
2. Modify "childEntity". change fields "Field1" & "Field3", but not "Field2".
3. The changes made in second entity works but not the parent entity.

I think that ParentEntity is not marked to "update" because in some place in the java logic JPA doesn't detect the key of this entity change.

ParentEntity
Id|Field1|Field2|Field3|...
1|12345|10000|123456789

SecondEntity
Id|Field3
10000|...

This is my entities structure. Sorry I can't put them full, but for the relation I think that it's enough.

```
@Table(name = "TABLE1")
public class ParentEntity{

    //id

    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "FIELD1", name = "FIELD1", nullable = false),
            @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "FIELD2", name = "FIELD2", nullable = false),
            @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "FIELD3", name = "FIELD3", updatable = false, insertable = false, nullable = false)})
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private SecondEntity childEntity;

    //getter y setter

}

@Table(name = "TABLE2", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"FIELD1", "FIELD2", "FIELD3"})})
public class SecondEntity {
    ....
}
```

1. I tried using 'refresh' method in my dao when I updated the first entity.
2. I tried to use saveAndFlush at moment of modifying first entity.
3. I tried to make a new find of the secondEntity after modifying and set it in the first, but nothing works.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Please don't only describe your problem but include your code so we can check it without trying to interpret your prosaic description. Also, you change the columns that make up the ID of `SecondEntity`? That sounds like a problem in itself, you *never* change the identifier.

Comment: can you post the code where you perform saves, updates, etc?